# String variable overwrites instead of concatenating in for-loop

Tags: linux, awk

## Context

I am trying to write a little awk program to analyze my PokerStars hand history. Hand histories are stored in text files and have the following format:

```
PokerStars Hand #225343166937:  Hold'em No Limit ($0.01/$0.02 USD) - 2021/03/30 16:14:07 ET
Table 'Pippa V' 6-max Seat #2 is the button
Seat 2: user1 ($2.12 in chips) 
Seat 3: user2 ($2.28 in chips) 
Seat 4: me ($2 in chips) 
Seat 5: user3 ($1.95 in chips) 
Seat 6: user4 ($2.06 in chips) 
user2: posts small blind $0.01
me: posts big blind $0.02
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to me [7d 9c]
user3: folds 
user4: folds 
user1: raises $0.04 to $0.06
user2: folds 
me: folds 
Uncalled bet ($0.04) returned to user1
user1 collected $0.05 from pot
user1: doesn't show hand 
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot $0.05 | Rake $0 
Seat 2: user1 (button) collected ($0.05)
Seat 3: user2 (small blind) folded before Flop
Seat 4: me (big blind) folded before Flop
Seat 5: user3 folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 6: user4 folded before Flop (didn't bet)



PokerStars Hand #225343172788:  Hold'em No Limit ($0.01/$0.02 USD) - 2021/03/30 16:14:17 ET
Table 'Pippa V' 6-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 2: user1 ($2.15 in chips) 
...
```

(Usernames have been changed to respect the players' privacy)

Each record (=hand) is seperated by three line breaks. I came as far as to seperate the hands into records, then loop over each line to save the relevant data into variables and print them. My little awk program looks like this:

```
BEGIN{
  RS="\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";
  FS="\n";
  OFS=",";
  print "Hand ID,Game Type,Time,Holecards";
}
{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
  {
    if ($i ~ /^PokerStars Hand/)
    {
      split($i, aHand, " ");
      handID = aHand[3];
      gameType = aHand[5]" "aHand[6]" "aHand[7]" "aHand[8];
      dateTime = aHand[10]" "aHand[11]" "aHand[12];
    }
    if ($i ~ /^Dealt to /)
    {
      split($i, aHoleCards, " ");
      holeCards = aHoleCards[4]" "aHoleCards[5];
    }
  }
  print(handID, gameType, dateTime, holeCards);
  #printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n", handID, gameType, dateTime, holeCards); # Same problem here
}
```

## The problem

The output I am expecting to get (for the first hand) is:

```
Hand ID,Game Type,Time,Holecards
#225343172788:,No Limit ($0.01/$0.02 USD),2021/03/30 16:14:17 ET,[7d 9c]
```

However, the output is different. For the first record, the variables `handID`, `gameType`, and `dateTime` seem to be empty whereas the `holeCards` get printed. The other variables then show up on the second line but get somehow "overwritten" by the `holeCards` variable of the second record:

```
Hand ID,Game Type,Time,Holecards                                                                      
,,,[7d 9c]                                                                                                
,[Kd As]72788:,No Limit ($0.01/$0.02 USD),2021/03/30 16:14:17 ET
```

I hope my description isn't too confusing. I'm very confused myself with the result. I tried using `printf` instead of `print` but the result is the same. I suspect I'm mussing something simple here.

Comment: Welcome to SO and special thanks for adding your code, samples and posting a detailed level question kudos. Coming to your question now, when I run your code I am getting exact expected output which you posted. I see you have put `\r` in your RS which are control M characters, so could you please confirm if you need them in your file?

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. I initially tried "\n\n\n" as the RS but somehow awk didn't find any occurrences (I checked NR at the end of the program and it was always 1). After changing it to what it is now, awk recognizes the different hands as records.
I did find this confusing myself (also because I do find 129 occurences of "\n\n\n" when using vim) but i stuck with it since it seemed to be the only way to make awk recognize the three line breaks.
Do you think the issue is related to the RS?

Comment: Which OS and text editor are you using ? Newline (aka end-of-line aka EOL) is `\n` under Unix and '\r\n' under Windows by default. The text file might use Windows EOL.

Comment: I'm using Arch Linux but the input files were generated in Windows (which then explains the `\r\n` weirdness). The encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: I don't understand why you have `\r\n` and also `\n` alone. Should it be always `\r\n` ? Unless only the records are separated Windows-style and the fiels Unix-style.

Comment: @DavidHk - The problem complexity could be reduced by first converting the file from Windows to Unix line endings.